# Splitting string twice and getting only specific elements

Tags: python, pandas

The following dataframe shows the purchases (conversions) generated by each marketing campaign path. For example, 10 users purchased a product after clicking on the ads of Campaigns A and B:

```
|                      path                          |  conversions | 
                      ------                             ---------        
| Campaign A | Laptop | Dec,Campaign B | Jan  |Phone |     10       | 
| Campaign C | Aug    | Camera,Campaign D2022 | Game |     35       |
```

The expected output is the following:

```
|  product    |  conversions | 
   ------         ---------        
| Laptop,Phone|     10       | 
| Camera,Game |     35       |
```

I only want to display the products that the ad campaigns refer to and its corresponding conversions. Please note that the position of the products' names may differ and that some campaigns do not have the same n° of elements (e.g. Campaign D2022).

Also, the order of the interactions with the campaigns is relevant: Campaign A, Campaign B != Campaign B, Campaign A.

I tried to solve it like this, but it did not work:

```
df['path']=df['path'].replace(' | ',',').str.split() 

journey=df['path']

items=['Laptop','Phone','Camera','Game']

df['product']=[x for x in journey if x in items]
```

After running the code above, I received an error message:

```
Length of values (0) does not match length of index (80566)
```

Comment: So, you split each cell at `','`, then you split the parts using `' | '` and take the middle part.  Easy to do with `apply`.  What have you tried?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes. I split it twice and tried to get only the elements that were present in a list with the products' names. Nonetheless, it did not work.

Comment: @programmer987, please share the code you tried so we can help more effectively

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide the code you used

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but this is the kind of thing you need:

```
def get_products(path):
    return ','.join( part.split(' | ')[1] for part in path.split(',') )
...
df['product'] = df['path'].apply(get_products)
```

Comment: Thank you! Nonetheless, I received an error message saying that the index is out of range. I updated the question with the following info: the position of the products' names may differ and some campaigns do not have the same n° of elements.

Comment: In that case, automated parsing may not be possible.  How can you possibly figure out which part is the one you want?

Comment: @programmer987, can you print the line that gave this error and update your `path` examples so they better capture the string variability you want to parse? Agree that if there isn't a discernible pattern then parsing errors are unavoidable